# Any way to recover data from a device that had its partition table corrupted?

Tags: twrp, data-recovery, boot-loop, partitions

So, I have this custom ROM that occasionally had a bootloop here and there. Usually, I wiped and reinstalled. Recently, the ROM became very stable, and if I just don't touch anything on bootup, all is fine, but someone else touched the phone. I don't know if they accidentally messed anything up but the phone again went into the bootloop.

I tried `adb sideload flash` the ROM to a newer version in the hope that the `boot.img` gets fixed, and the flashing worked as I now see the new version in recovery, but I still had the bootloop. I probably made a mistake as I flashed `boot.img` with `fastboot flash boot` on an A/B device with ramdisk.

The phone structure is a huge mess, but I ran it with Magisk on the boot, and sometimes recovery in the ramdisk. Hopefully, I haven't made things worse and I can retrieve the data.

When I `fastboot boot twrp`, I saw that everything internal storage was 0 MB. The problem is that the ROM is Android 13. I hope that my data isn't encrypted. Usually, I had access to everything before this bootloop as I decrypted everything when I set it up in the first place.

I just did the update from `adb sideload` and flashed `boot.img` and recovery nothing else. Yet in TWRP, it displayed data as 0 MB.

I don't know what to try and see if the data is still there. Thank you for reading.